# convert string to int?

Tags: python, string, int

Working on a letter-guessing game.

Why is it that in the following example, when I hardcode the value of the variable, "userGuessPosition" to 2, the code works as expected.

```
secretWord = ('music')
userGuessPosition = 2 
slice1 = (secretWord.__len__()) - userGuessPosition - 1  
print (secretWord[slice1:userGuessPosition])
```

But when I rely on the input() function and type in 2 at the prompt, nothing happens?

```
secretWord = ('music')
userGuessPosition = 0
userGuessPosition == input()
slice1 = (secretWord.__len__()) - userGuessPosition - 1  
print (secretWord[slice1:userGuessPosition])
```

I assume this is because my keyboard input of "2" is being seen as a string and not an integer. If this is the case, then I'm unclear on the proper syntax to convert it.

Comment: Please tag the programming language you're using.

Comment: You need to add a tag for whatever language this is in. I'm still not sure after reading it.

Answer (score 5):

```
userGuessPosition = int(input())
```

(Single `=`; `int` converts a string to an int)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not that the input is recognized as a string, but rather in the syntax: you're doing a comparison operation where you should be doing an assignment operation.

You have to use

```
userGuessPosition = input()
```

instead of

```
userGuessPosition == input()
```

The `input()` function actually does convert the input number into the most appropriate type, sp that should not be an issue. If however you need to convert a string (say, `my_string`) to an integer, all you  need to do is `my_int = int(my_string)`.

### EDIT

As mentioned below by @HenryKeiter, depending on your Python version, you may in fact need to convert the return value of `input()` to an integer by hand, since `raw_input()` (which always takes in the input as a string) was renamed to `input()` in Python 3.

Comment: Worth mentioning: depending on his Python version, he **may** in fact need to convert the return value of `input()` to an int by hand, since `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in Python 3.